# PHP and Mysql, export from one table and import to another one

Tags: php, mysql, merge, insert-into

I am trying to export text from two colomns from a table to format it with html and then merge it in a single colomn in a new table.

I managed to export everything but I cant get to insert $text_comp into post_content properly. This code inserts 0 for each row into the post_content colomn.

Here is my code :

```
function clean_string($value) {
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
}
return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}



$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  table8");
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();}




while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {



$id_article_c =  $row['id_article_complement'];
$id_article_n =  $row['id_article'];
$text_comp =  "<h3>". $row['titre_article_complement']."</h3><p>".$row['contenu_article_complement'] ."</p>";



$test_insert = mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO wordpress_test(post_content, id_article,id_article_complement) VALUES("'.clean_string($text_comp).'", "'.$id_article_n.'","'.$id_article_c.'")');
 if (!$test_insert) {
     printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();}
}
```

**EDIT**: My bad, this code works. the problem came from the SQL Table where I set the data type wrong. I dont remember exactly but it was something like `int` instead of `TEXT`

Comment: I am sorry this code actually worked, the problem came from the structure of MySQL table.

Answer (score 0):

Why use two queries?  SQL can do this in a single query:

```
INSERT INTO wordpress_test(post_content, id_article, id_article_complement)
    SELECT titre_article_complement, id_article, id_article_complement
    FROM  table8;
```